# MySQL - Unknown column when use LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, join

I'm getting some problems making a simple `SELECT` w/ `LEFT JOIN` query:

```
SELECT 
   a.sttgs_id, a.sttgs_description, 
   (c.uss_id IS NOT NULL) as has 
FROM 
   (mt_user b, mt_settings a 
       LEFT JOIN mt_user_settings c 
             ON c.sttgs_id=a.sttgs_id AND 
             b.usr_id=c.usr_id
   )
WHERE  c.usr_id=2
```

PHPMyAdmin says: `#1054 - Unknown column 'b.usr_id' in 'on clause'`.

I really don't know other way to do the `SELECT`.

Greetings.

Edit: `show create table mt_user`

[image]

Comment: What are the fields in mt_user?

Comment: Remove the parentheses under `FROM`

Comment: mt_user has: `usr_id`, `usr_login`, `usr_passwd`, `usr_firstname`, etc...

Comment: Can you post the results of `show create table mt_user`

Comment: Do not mix implicit (comma-) and explicit JOIN syntax. In fact. Don't use implicit join syntax at all

Comment: @JhonatanSandoval Thanks, shut me up - everything looks right :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
      a.sttgs_id, 
      a.sttgs_description, 
      c.uss_id  as has 
FROM mt_user b 
LEFT JOIN mt_user_settings c on b.usr_id=c.usr_id
LEFT JOIN  mt_settings a ON c.sttgs_id=a.sttgs_id  --you may need INNER JOIN here
WHERE  c.usr_id=2
AND c.uss_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Well, It didn't solve my problem. But i created another post to specify why i want to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562855/mysql-create-a-virtual-column-to-verify-if-data-exists-on-anothers . Thank you for answer.