# Create a virtual column to verify if data exists on anothers

Tags: mysql, join

**mt_user**:

```
usr_id               usr_login          usr_passwd
  1                   user1               user1
  2                   user2               user2
  3                   user3               user3
  4                   user4               user4
```

**mt_settings**:

```
sttgs_id                        sttgs_description
   1                                 Setting 1
   2                                 Setting 2
   3                                 Setting 3
   4                                 Setting 4
   5                                 Setting 5
```

**mt_user_settings**:

```
uss_id               usr_id                   sttgs_id
  1                    1                         1
  2                    1                         2
  3                    2                         5
  4                    3                         2
  5                    3                         3
  6                    3                         5
  7                    4                         4
```

What I need to show is data like this:

`WHERE usr_id='2'` :

```
sttgs_id                   sttgs_description                 has it? (virtual_column)
   1                          Setting 1                              0
   2                          Setting 2                              0
   3                          Setting 3                              0
   4                          Setting 4                              0
   5                          Setting 5                              1
```

`WHERE usr_id='3'` :

```
sttgs_id                   sttgs_description                 has it? (virtual_column)
   1                          Setting 1                              0
   2                          Setting 2                              1
   3                          Setting 3                              1
   4                          Setting 4                              0
   5                          Setting 5                              1
```

How could I do it correctly?

Comment: You should really format the part after `Where usr_id = '2'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.sttgs_id, s.sttgs_description, IF(st.uss_id,1,0) as `has it`
FROM mt_user u
JOIN mt_settings s
LEFT JOIN mt_user_settings us ON us.usr_id = u.usr_id AND us.sttgs_id = s.sttgs_id
WHERE u.usr_id = 2
```

you can also do it without the users table

```
SELECT s.sttgs_id, s.sttgs_description, IF(st.uss_id,1,0) as `has it`
FROM  mt_settings s
LEFT JOIN mt_user_settings us ON us.usr_id = 2 AND us.sttgs_id = s.sttgs_id
```